# Search for a pattern and replace entire column with searched pattern in a pipe delimited file

Tags: unix, awk

I have pipe delimited file with 30 columns and this may change. .I need to search for certain pattern on all columns  and when match is found I need to replace entire column with matched pattern.Here is the example

```
Id|col1|col2|col3
20|eff ghb abcxrar Kano|abcrar|thgh abctgggrar 
30|abcrar|fgt Lon abcfgtrar|abctrar def
```

Need to search for string that starts with abc and finishes with rar and replace entire column with it when matched
Output should be :

```
Id|col1|col2|col3
20|abcxrar|abcrar|abctgggrar
30|abcrar|abcfgtrar|abctrar
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please post your sample Input and expected sample output in CODE TAGS with all conditions so that we could help you on this.

Comment: also add what you've tried to question... SO is about getting help with code you tried but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk -F"|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){num=split($i,array," ");for(j=1;j<=num;j++){if(match(array[j],/^abc.*rar$/)){$i=substr(array[j],RSTART,RLENGTH)}}}} 1' OFS="|"  Input_file
```

Adding a non one liner form of solution too now:

```
awk -F"|" '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    num=split($i,array," ");
    for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
      if(match(array[j],/^abc.*rar$/)){
        $i=substr(array[j],RSTART,RLENGTH)}}}
}
1' OFS="|"  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Id|col1|col2|col3
20|abcxrar|abcrar|abctgggrar
30|abcrar|abcfgtrar|abctrar
```